# Linked Lists changes

Tags: c, linked-list

If we have two lists: List 1 and List 2 (where list1/list2 are pointers to the first node of two linked lists) and execute the following pseudocode:

```
set temp to list1
loop (temp link not null)
  set temp to temp link
end loop 
set temp link to list2
```

Would the above join list 1 and list 2?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: You should use a for() loop instead of a while(), much clearer!

Comment: @wildplasser but does it join list 1 and 2?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know temp's type, and I don't know what is the result/return. I also don't see the case where list1 (or list2) is empty (NULL). In short: your pseudocode is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would.

The code loops through list1 until it finds the last element of the list. Then it sets the link pointer of the last element to point to the beginning of list2, effectively joining the two lists.